# Start Workflow after adding new document to documents library OOTB?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I want to start a Workflow after a adding new document to an document library in SharePoint 2013 OOTB.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Does my answer help you? Please let us know.

Comment: yes that was useful to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just focus on **two** things:

1. Workflow will never start automatically with system account.
2. Check the options Start workflow automatically when an item is created or changed from Workflow Start Options.

   [image]

Maybe start here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2011/07/08/understanding-workflow-starting-parameters-part-1/

or here: https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/creating-custom-workflows-with-sharepoint-designer-2013.cfm

I wrote a blog post about "How to create your first 2013 SharePoint Desginer Workflow". You can check that out here: https://afrait.com/blog/how-to-create-your-first-2013-workflow-de-en/